# Installing rails-3.0.0.beta4 , and getting the royal (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

First let me explain that I've created a million lib directories scouring out all the different responses to this same problem but none of them have really done the trick..

I've tried

```
sudo mkdir /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.0.0.beta4/lib
sudo mkdir /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9/gems/rails-3.0.0.beta4/lib
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.0.0.beta4/lib
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.0.0.beta3/lib
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/rails-3.0.0.beta3/lib
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/rails-3.0.0.beta4/lib
```

My Ruby -v is : ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i386-darwin10.3.0]

Those most current release of rails --pre is  rails-3.0.0.beta4 .

So I'm assuming it 'has' to be rails-3.0.0.beta4/lib that it needs, just not sure where.

I am using .rvm  . Running 'which ruby' returns :

```
/Users/johnsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/ruby
```

Is there a clever way to figure out where exactly that /lib would be on my box?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You didn't post the actual error you are seeing, that's not very helpful. Also, official reports mention that Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.1 don't go well together. Either use Ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.2 RCs.

Comment: Word. I think the major problem is I'm using RVM. I'm just wiping everything off and starting again, but definately taking your advice and grabbing 1.9.2 or 1.8.7 . Many many thanks Shteef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES!

Ok so what I had was a discombobulated pile of dog doo doo code, a mess of gems, and rubies. It kinda reminded me of the Genie's lamp when he went out on a bender one night.

I just uninstalled that entire rvm branch, started a new one with 1.9.2-head on Shteef's recommendation, installed rubygems (no problems this time), and installed rails3 with no problems!!!

Now I can be cool like everyone else!